# $size, $bits, verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

What is the difference between `$size` and `$bits` operator in verilog.?
if I've variables, `[9:0]a`,`[6:0]b`,`[31:0]c`.

```
c <= [($size(a)+$size(b)-1]-:$bits(b)];
```

What will be the output at 'c' from the above expression?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$size` shall return the number of elements in the dimension, which is equivalent to `$high - $low + 1`. It is relative to the dimension, not only bit counts. If the type is 1D packed array or integral type, it is equal to `$bits`.

`$bits` system function returns the number of bits required to hold an expression as a bit stream.

```
$bits ( [expression|type_identifier] )
```

It returns 0 when called with a dynamically sized type that is currently empty. It is an error to use the `$bits` system function directly with a dynamically sized type identifier.

I have no idea about your question, `c <= [($size(a)+$size(b)-1]-:$bits(b)];`. Is it a valid expression in RHS? Are you talking about the array range expression, `[n +: m]` or `[n -: m]` ?

Comment: `$size(a)` = 10, `$size(b) = 7`, `$bits(b)` = 7: `c <= x[17-1-:7]` These are all standard types so `$bits` and `$size` would be the same.

Comment: You are right. But I just don't realize is a typo or real intent for `c <= [17+7-1]-:7];`

Comment: Ah yes, typo 17+7-1. Also note the question has no variable it is just a range so it is not valid verilog.

Comment: @jclin, yes. you are right. i'm talking about the array range, [n+:m] and [n-:m].
can you please explain about the significance of representing range in this type.
thanks

Comment: The array range expression `[n +: m]` or `[n -: m]`, `n` is the starting index, `+:` or `-:` is the incremental or decremental direction. `m` is how many elements to count up/down. For example `[4+:4]` == `[4:7]`, `[3-:4]` == `[3:0]`

Answer (score 34):

`$size()` gives the number of bits for a single dimension. `$bits()` gives the number of bits to completely represent the variable.

For example:

```
reg [9:0] a;
reg [9:0] b [5:0];

initial begin
  $display("a Size ", $size(a));
  $display("a Bits ", $bits(a));
  $display("b Size ", $size(b));
  $display("b Bits ", $bits(b)) ;
end
```

Gives :

```
a Size          10
a Bits          10
b Size           6 // Depth of memory
b Bits          60 // Width * Depth
```

In your case you just have 1 dimensional arrays, not memories or structs so `$size()` and `$bits()` would be the same thing.