# Analyze a packed structure in SystemVerilog to determine it's size?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog is there a way to analyze a packed structure and determine it's overall size in bits?

```
typedef struct packed unsigned {
    logic [15:0]    field_1;
    logic  [7:0]    field_2;
    logic [15:0]    field_3;
    logic  [4:0]    field_4;
} my_struct;
```

For example, I would like to be able to determine programmatic-ally that the size of the above structure is 45.

I've looked at the "Aggregate data types" section (Chapter 7) of the [IEEE 1800-2012 SystemVerilog Language Reference Manual](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), and didn't see anything like this.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: [Related Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13345976/97073)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$bits()` from [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 20.6.2 *Expression size system function*:

> The `$bits` system function returns the number of bits required to hold an expression as a bit stream.

Direct example from the [LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html):

> ... Given the declaration:
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
> logic valid;
> bit [8:1] data;
> } MyType;
> ```
>
> the expression `$bits(MyType)` shall return 9, the number of data bits needed by a variable of type MyType.