# Does $size(or $bits) on 1-D array in verilog compute on current value or the maximum value the array can hold?

Tags: size, verilog

In Verilog, suppose I use the `$size` function on a 1-D vector. Would it give me the size of the value it holds or the size of the maximum value it can hold?

For example:

```
reg[10:0] a;
a=11'd3;
$display("Size of a is ",$size(a));
```

In this scenario, would it display "Size of a is 11", since this is the bit length of the max value that the vector can hold? Or would it say "Size of a is 2" since the actual bit length of the value in `a`, i.e, 3 is 2-bits?

P.S. I am new to verilog. So please excuse any syntax errors. Thank you

Comment: Trying on a simulator (or several simulators) and find out. http://edaplayground.com has 9 options of 5 different online simulators.

Comment: Could you accept the best answer and upvote useful answers so that we know the question has been answered, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, $size() gives the number of bits for a single dimension. Hence it should display 11. You can have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13345976/3951497 for more details.

Comment: I tried it out on ModelSim and `$size` and `$bits` don't seem to work. However I did some digging around and `$clog2` seems to work better. Thanks for all the help