# Is there a system verilog task which returns the length of a reg / logic?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, synthesis

It would be nice to have something similar to `sizeof()` from C. Needless to mention I don't expect it to be synthesizeable.

Comment: `$size` for number of bits in a given dimension. `$bits` for overall number of bits count. Refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340301/size-bits-verilog) link for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$bits(variable)` is what you want.